# countifs same criteria in diffrent criteria ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to countifs values between two dates and need to lookup same criteria in different criteria ranges (columns I,J,K) values.I used below formula in N6.Answer should 3.between given dates how many rows are common for given line  no in(M4) between given start and end date.Please advise.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,">="&N2,A2:A7,"<="&N3,H2:H7,"PASS",I2:I7,M4,J2:J7,M4,K2:K7,M4)
```

[image]

Comment: The outcome is logical. Your criteria not tells the formula to count for cells that have `33A` is both columns `I`, `J` and `K`. It's more likely you were wanting the formula to check if the value is present in any of those three instead.

Comment: re there any possibility to make this logical.how can we modify this formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `33A` occurs just once in columns `I-K` you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7>=N2)*(A2:A7<=N3)*(H2:H7="PASS")*(I2:K7=M4))
```

Comment: how do we sum  column E values under same conditions.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you just add `*(E2:E7)` at the end before the last closing paranthesis @KarenSandria. If not, then please open a new question. New question = New topic on SO.